# Soundcloud html5 player not playing on ipad mini

Tags: ios, ipad, widget, mobile-safari, soundcloud

I have seen the player doesn't work on my ipad for my site and many other sites with player widgets html5. Is there an easy fix for this please? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us an example (live demo/url, screenshot, log, code, etc)?

Comment: Yes thanks it is www.mikegeorgiades.com/listen.htm

Comment: Working fine for me on an iPad 2 running 7.1.2 (11D257) (http://imgur.com/wVZYcnj). Even ran it through the Safari mobile debugger and did not find any issues. What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: your example seems to work for me on iOS as well :( could you give more examples of where it doesn't work? When you say “doesn’t work”, what exactly do you refer to?

Comment: Thanks, I contacted soundcloud and it's a known chrome issue, so seems there's nothing can be done at present, thanks anyway.

Comment: @user1684099 What was the error behavior of your widget in Chrome?